# Recaptcha in Django without forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, recaptcha

I am putting together a Django app that has forms on the site, but I am rendering those forms manually (i.e. actually typing out each field and submitting them with AJAX).

How can I integrate Recaptcha into my forms? Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question was asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526399/django-forms-wizard-and-recaptcha) lots of options there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just using this python client for recaptcha:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/recaptcha-client

then my view looks like this:

```
captcha_key = get_config('RECAPTCHA_PUB_KEY',None)
recaptcha_challenge_field = request.POST.get('recaptcha_challenge_field', None)
recaptcha_response_field = request.POST.get('recaptcha_response_field', None)
check_captcha = captcha.submit(recaptcha_challenge_field, recaptcha_response_field, settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY, request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
if check_captcha.is_valid is False:
    log.info('captcha_error : %s' % check_captcha.error_code)
    return {'TEMPLATE':template_name,'captcha_error': True,'register_form': f,'captcha_key':captcha_key ,'next':redirect_to}
```

Answer (score 3):

recaptcha-client doesn't work with python3. I ended up using django-recaptcha (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-recaptcha/1.0). The brief documentation explains how to implement recaptcha using the formfield 'ReCaptchaField', but you can just use the submit function from captcha.client like this:

```
import captcha.client
```

[...]

```
recaptcha_response = captcha.client.submit(  
    request.POST.get('recaptcha_challenge_field'),  
    request.POST.get('recaptcha_response_field'),  
    '[[privatekey]]',  
    request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],)
```

Then you check whether `recaptcha_response.is_valid`.

No need to add recaptcha to your INSTALLED_APPS or anything.